# AVPlayer not playing despite having correct URL

Tags: swift, audio, avfoundation, avplayer, avplayeritem

I need help from my code since I can't figure out why my AVPlayer can't play the audio.
Here would be my function:

```html
@IBAction func pausePlayAudio(_ sender: CustomButton) {
    let audioSourceURL: String = "[Site]/module_lesson_uploads/audios/"
    let audioString: String = audioSourceURL + (sender.paramaters["thisAudioURL"] as! String)
    let audioURL = URL(string: audioString)

    print(audioString)

    let playerItem: AVPlayerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: audioURL!)
    let audioPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)

    audioPlayer.play()
}
```

it is called here:

```html
pausePlayButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ModuleLessonElementsViewController.pausePlayAudio(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
pausePlayButton.paramaters["thisAudioURL"] = content
```

and here would be the console's result from printing the passed String:

```html
[Site]/module_lesson_uploads/audios/228F0E3-1576580339.mp3
2019-12-19 11:54:34.524954+0800 AppUI[3807:70260] [] nw_endpoint_flow_copy_multipath_subflow_counts Called on non-Multipath connection
2019-12-19 11:54:34.688244+0800 AppUI[3807:70259] [] nw_endpoint_flow_copy_multipath_subflow_counts Called on non-Multipath connection
2019-12-19 11:54:34.718316+0800 AppUI[3807:70261] [] nw_endpoint_flow_copy_multipath_subflow_counts Called on non-Multipath connection
2019-12-19 11:54:34.912438+0800 AppUI[3807:70259] [] nw_endpoint_flow_copy_multipath_subflow_counts Called on non-Multipath connection
2019-12-19 11:54:34.913975+0800 AppUI[3807:70259] [] nw_endpoint_flow_copy_multipath_subflow_counts Called on non-Multipath connection
[Site]/module_lesson_uploads/audios/4AB4136-1576647127.mp3
2019-12-19 11:55:04.511064+0800 AppUI[3807:70259] [] nw_endpoint_flow_copy_multipath_subflow_counts Called on non-Multipath connection
2019-12-19 11:55:04.742723+0800 AppUI[3807:70262] [] nw_endpoint_flow_copy_multipath_subflow_counts Called on non-Multipath connection
2019-12-19 11:55:04.795568+0800 AppUI[3807:70262] [] nw_endpoint_flow_copy_multipath_subflow_counts Called on non-Multipath connection
2019-12-19 11:55:05.042987+0800 AppUI[3807:70262] [] nw_endpoint_flow_copy_multipath_subflow_counts Called on non-Multipath connection
2019-12-19 11:55:05.049440+0800 AppUI[3807:70262] [] nw_endpoint_flow_copy_multipath_subflow_counts Called on non-Multipath connection
```

It seems to be working, but the audio was not playing. Any help or explanation would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked your code and discovered such a pattern:

- if I define and initialize `audioPlayer` before `viewDidLoad` - then `audioPlayer` works in 100% of cases (I worked with [this](https://dl.espressif.com/dl/audio/ff-16b-2c-44100hz.mp3) audio)
- if I define and initialize `audioPlayer` as you (at `pausePlayAudio`) - sometimes it works, sometimes not.

Please, check this:

```
var audioPlayer = AVPlayer()

@IBAction func pausePlayAudio(_ sender: CustomButton) {
    let audioSourceURL: String = "[Site]/module_lesson_uploads/audios/"
    let audioString: String = audioSourceURL + (sender.paramaters["thisAudioURL"] as! String)
    let audioURL = URL(string: audioString)

    print(audioString)

    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: audioURL!)
    self.audioPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)

    self.audioPlayer.play()
}
```

Comment: although I did get the idea, you need to do audioPlayer.replaceCurrentItem(with: playerItem)

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is that you are creating a functional scope instance for the audio player. It will release immidiately after the execution and that's why it's not playing. 
Make a class variable of the audioPlayer object and do the same thing. It will sure work. Also, Currently your URL is from server so wait for a few seconds to receive enough buffer data to play.

Comment: Would it be the same case for the videoPlayer? May I chat with you. I have another problem, this time it's with a video. @Amrit Trivedi

Comment: can you please take a look here,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59483652/avplayerlayer-not-playing-video-but-the-audio-is-good