# AVPlayerLayer not playing video but the audio is good

Tags: swift, avplayer, avplayerlayer

I have somewhat of a confusing problem. 
I declared these variables in my class:

```
var audioPlayer = AVPlayer()
var videoPlayer = AVPlayer()
var videoLayer = AVPlayerLayer()
```

I have these codes for adding the container of the videoPlayer:

```
let aspectHeight = view.frame.width * 9/16
let viewFrame = CGRect(x: 5, y: 0, width: view.frame.width - 10, height: aspectHeight)
let layerFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width - 10, height: aspectHeight)

videoPlayerContainerView.frame = viewFrame
videoPlayerViewController.frame = viewFrame
videoLayer.frame = layerFrame

videoLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
videoPlayerContainerView.layer.addSublayer(videoLayer)
videoPlayerContainerView.addSubview(videoPlayerViewController)

videoElementContainerView.addView(newView: videoPlayerContainerView)
```

I also have this function (I replaced the passed argument with a temporary URL):

```
@IBAction func pausePlayVideo(_ sender: CustomButton) {
    let videoString = videoSourceURL + (sender.paramaters["thisVideoURL"] as! String)
    let videoURL = URL(string: "https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4")
    videoPlayer = AVPlayer(url: videoURL!)
    videoLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: videoPlayer)

    videoPlayer.play()
}
```

I'm calling it here:

```
pausePlayButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ModuleLessonElementsViewController.pausePlayVideo(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
pausePlayButton.paramaters["thisVideoURL"] = content
```

Here would be the view:
[The layer was added, the audio plays but the video does not.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/peCqg.png)

When the button is pressed, the audio plays, however the video does not. Am I missing something important here?

Comment: Add your videolayer add sub layer code at the end . That’s the only issue. Right now videoplayer controller added above your layer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very simple. Early on, you say:

```
videoPlayerContainerView.layer.addSublayer(videoLayer)
```

Okay, so you have a player layer `videoLayer`, associated with no player, and it is in the interface now. Fine.

Later, when the button is pressed, you say:

```
@IBAction func pausePlayVideo(_ sender: CustomButton) {
    // ...
    videoLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: videoPlayer)
    videoPlayer.play()
}
```

So what just happened? You threw away your reference in `videoLayer` to the layer that you previously added to the interface, and substituted for it a completely new player layer that you just created, and that is *not* in the interface. Okay, so the video layer you have associated with the player is not in the interface, so you can hear the player but you can't see anything.

Comment: Oh, so what I should've done is videoLayer.player = videoPlayer. THANK YO VERY MUCH!!! Also, I did all these so that I can play multiple videos from API. Would this method work @matt?